Can I set Google Cloud Storage objects metadata from browser side without turning off CORS?
I want to set metadata on a file stored in a bucket on Google Cloud Storage.  Specifically, I want to set a tag named <tag> to have value <value>, where both <tag> and <value> are set by the user.
To the best of my knowledge, this is done by sending an authenticated PUT request which has the header:
X-Goog-Meta-<tagname>: value
But CORS appears to get in the way, since I would have to have configured CORS to accept a header of the form X-Goog-Meta-<tagname>.   This is not instantaneous - they say it can take up to 30 minutes for new CORS policies to propagate.  Even 10 seconds would detract from the kind of functioning I want to do.
The only thing I can think of is to send the request from the server side and ignore CORS altogether  (or turn CORS off, but no).  Am I missing something?  Is there some other way to do this?

You could configure CORS to allow arbitrary request headers (from select Web origins). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#sect2

Wow, didn't realize I could do that.  It sounds simpler, thanks!

You can also check this documentation on setting up and viewing CORS configurations and CORS configuration examples as the configuration and example is for Cloud Storage itself. These also provide troubleshooting CORS request if unexpected behavior is encountered.

Posting as a community wiki based on the comment of @jub0bs:

You could configure CORS to allow arbitrary request headers (from select Web origins). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#sect2

In addition, you can check this CORS configuration examples that you can check as reference.
